# ошибка E0167, как исправить?

Tags: c++

есть функция:

```
int Compare(char S[105], int count, int N, int i, int k, int j)
{
    N = strlen(S);
    for (int k = i; k < N; k++)
    {
        if ((S[k] != S[j]) || (k == j))
            count++;
        j--;
    }
    return count;
}
```

при вызове её

```
count = Compare(S[105], count, N, i, k, j);
```

появляется ошибка: E0167    аргумент типа "char" несовместим с параметром типа "char *"
как её исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не сказали практически ничего. Ни как объявлена функция, ни как описаны переменные, которые вы ей передаете. Приходится просто догадываться...

Видимо, у вас `S` — это массив `char`, функция описана как

```
Compare(char* S....
```

или

```
Compare(char S[]....
```

В результате она ждет массив `char`, а вы ей передаете **один элемент** этого массива — 106-ой... Передавайте ей сам массив.

После того, как вы дополнили вопрос — все остается в силе. Вызывать надо как

```
Compare(S, ...
```

И еще — зачем вы сами себя ограничиваете размером массива? Тем более что он нигде не участвует! Как и, кстати говоря, передаваемые ей аргументы! Просто опишите функцию как

```
int Compare(char S[])
{
    int count, N, i, k, j;
    ....
```

Так оно короче, понятнее, и не надо создавать липовые переменные в месте вызова функции.

Comment: Интересно, за что минус?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Наверное, кто-то от досады, что не успел. Или от "такой личной неприязни, что кушать не может" (с) :)

Comment: Вот разве что :)